# Displaying posts from only users the user follows with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Necessary tables

```
   recipe_post    
    +-----------+-----------+-------+
    | recipe_id | posted_by | title |
    +-----------+-----------+-------+

friend_request (followers table)   
    +----------+-----------+
    | follower | following |
    +----------+-----------+
```

This query gets the ingredients from a recipe_ingredients table and matches it with a users_ingredients table and returns all posts with a status of whether the user can or cant cook

```
SELECT u.uid, ri.recipe_id,
       COUNT(ui.i_id) AS available_ingredients, -- Number of ingredients the user has that are required to cook this recipe
       COUNT(ri.i_id) AS required_ingredients,  -- Number of ingredients that are required to cook this recipe
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(ui.i_id) = COUNT(ri.i_id) THEN 'can_cook'
         WHEN COUNT(ui.i_id) > 0 THEN 'has_some_ingredients'
         ELSE 'has_no_ingredients'
       END AS state,
rp.recipe_id,rp.name,rp.description
FROM users u
CROSS JOIN recipe_ingredients ri
LEFT JOIN userIngredients ui ON(ri.i_id = ui.i_id AND u.uid = ui.uid)
INNER JOIN recipe_post rp ON rp.recipe_id = ri.recipe_id
WHERE u.uid = 1 --matching with user 1
GROUP BY u.uid, ri.recipe_id, rp.recipe_id
ORDER BY u.uid, ri.recipe_id;
```

I have created another query that returns posts from only the users they follow

```
SELECT * FROM recipe_post p
INNER JOIN friend_requests f ON (f.following = p.posted_by)
WHERE f.follower = 5;
```

I'm having trouble with adding in this query to the first one so that it can only show posts from users they follow

Answer (score 0):

you can join your 2nd query as `subquery`.

```
SELECT u.uid
        , ri.recipe_id
        , COUNT(ui.i_id) AS available_ingredients -- Number of ingredients the user has that are required to cook this recipe
        , COUNT(ri.i_id) AS required_ingredients -- Number of ingredients that are required to cook this recipe
        , CASE WHEN COUNT(ui.i_id) = COUNT(ri.i_id) THEN 'can_cook'
            WHEN COUNT(ui.i_id) > 0 THEN 'has_some_ingredients'
            ELSE 'has_no_ingredients'
            END AS state
        , rp.recipe_id
        , rp.name
        , rp.description
FROM users u
CROSS JOIN recipe_ingredients ri
LEFT JOIN userIngredients ui ON(ri.i_id = ui.i_id AND u.uid = ui.uid)
INNER JOIN recipe_post rp ON rp.recipe_id = ri.recipe_id
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM recipe_post p
        INNER JOIN friend_requests f ON f.following = p.posted_by) as t1 on t1.recipe_id =  = rp.recipe_id
WHERE u.uid = 1 --matching with user 1
GROUP BY u.uid, ri.recipe_id, rp.recipe_id
ORDER BY u.uid, ri.recipe_id;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that Ive tried this and got a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add how you did with the other tables to join :

```
SELECT u.uid, ri.recipe_id,
       COUNT(ui.i_id) AS available_ingredients, -- Number of ingredients the user has that are required to cook this recipe
       COUNT(ri.i_id) AS required_ingredients,  -- Number of ingredients that are required to cook this recipe
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(ui.i_id) = COUNT(ri.i_id) THEN 'can_cook'
         WHEN COUNT(ui.i_id) > 0 THEN 'has_some_ingredients'
         ELSE 'has_no_ingredients'
       END AS state,
rp.recipe_id,rp.name,rp.description
FROM users u
CROSS JOIN recipe_ingredients ri
 LEFT JOIN userIngredients ui ON ri.i_id = ui.i_id AND u.uid = ui.uid
INNER JOIN recipe_post rp ON rp.recipe_id = ri.recipe_id
INNER JOIN friend_requests f ON f.following = rp.posted_by
WHERE u.uid = 1 --matching with user 1
  AND f.follower = 5
GROUP BY u.uid, ri.recipe_id, rp.recipe_id
ORDER BY u.uid, ri.recipe_id;
```